# tigervnc virtual screen is stuck after entering correct password on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: vnc

I have installed tigerVNC on ubuntu 20.04, I create the virtual session and access the server using vncviewer, after I entering correct password of the machine the login scree is staked. Behind the machine it's login, but in virtual session the screen is staked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After rebooting the gdm.service, it will be work for me.

1. **sudo systemctl restart gdm.service**
2. kill the currant vnc session, **vncserver -kill :vncsession number (ex- vncserver -kill :1**
3. start the new vncserver virtual session, **vncserver -localhost no**
4. try to login to the server via vnc viewer